# Entity Framework, Order Manager class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using the entity framework and want to structure a class for the orders. An order document is composed of a header and its properties, and several lines and their properties. Something like this:

```
[Table("DocumentHeaders")]
public class Header
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public int Number { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}


[Table("DocumentRows")]
public class Rows
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid HeaderId { get; set; }
   public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
   public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
   public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}


public class orders
{
   public orders()
   {
      Header = new Header();
      Rows = new List<Rows>();
   }

   public Header Header { get; set; }
   public IList<Rows> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

The class order is not an entity class but rather a class that aggregates entity classes managed by the context of the entity framework.
What I intend is to use this main class (orders) to add to the context. How to do this?

Comment: well easiest would probably be to modify the getters of header and rows (in the orders class) to automatically add the entities to the ef context but then you would have to have the context within the orders class

Comment: Why is `Header` not your main class? `orders` really doesn't contain any new information, so what do you expect to appear in the context? Please be precise and provide an example. Is `HeaderId` properly defined as foreign key? This might be important in order to simply add some navigation properties